# Python/Regex - Match .#,#. in String

Tags: python, regex

What regex can I use to match ".#,#." within a string.  It may or may not exist in the string.  Some examples with expected outputs might be:

```
Test1.0,0.csv      -> ('Test1', '0,0', 'csv')         (Basic Example)
Test2.wma          -> ('Test2', 'wma')                (No Match)
Test3.1100,456.jpg -> ('Test3', '1100,456', 'jpg')    (Basic with Large Number)
T.E.S.T.4.5,6.png  -> ('T.E.S.T.4', '5,6', 'png')     (Doesn't strip all periods)
Test5,7,8.sss      -> ('Test5,7,8', 'sss')            (No Match)
Test6.2,3,4.png    -> ('Test6.2,3,4', 'png')          (No Match, to many commas)
Test7.5,6.7,8.test -> ('Test7', '5,6', '7,8', 'test') (Double Match?)
```

The last one isn't too important and I would only expect that .#,#. would appear once.  Most files I'm processing, I would expect to fall into the first through fourth examples, so I'm most interested in those.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awww man. If only everyone would provide such an extensive list of examples that match and examples that fail...

Comment: @m.buettner I know, this is beautiful in comparison to 99% of regex questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow for multiple consecutive matches, use lookahead/lookbehind:

```
r'(?<=\.)\d+,\d+(?=\.)'
```

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\.)\d+,\d+(?=\.)', 'Test7.5,6.7,8.test')
['5,6', '7,8']
```

We can also use lookahead to perform the split as you want it:

```
import re
def split_it(s):
    pieces = re.split(r'\.(?=\d+,\d+\.)', s)
    pieces[-1:] = pieces[-1].rsplit('.', 1) # split off extension
    return pieces
```

Testing:

```
>>> print split_it('Test1.0,0.csv')
['Test1', '0,0', 'csv']
>>> print split_it('Test2.wma')
['Test2', 'wma']
>>> print split_it('Test3.1100,456.jpg')
['Test3', '1100,456', 'jpg']
>>> print split_it('T.E.S.T.4.5,6.png')
['T.E.S.T.4', '5,6', 'png']
>>> print split_it('Test5,7,8.sss')
['Test5,7,8', 'sss']
>>> print split_it('Test6.2,3,4.png')
['Test6.2,3,4', 'png']
>>> print split_it('Test7.5,6.7,8.test')
['Test7', '5,6', '7,8', 'test']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex `\.\d+,\d+\.` to find all matches for that pattern, but you will need to do a little extra to get the output you expect, especially since you want to treat `.5,6.7,8.` as two matches.

Here is one potential solution:

```
def transform(s):
    s = re.sub(r'(\.\d+,\d+)+\.', lambda m: m.group(0).replace('.', '\n'), s)
    return tuple(s.split('\n'))
```

Examples:

```
>>> transform('Test1.0,0.csv')
('Test1', '0,0', 'csv')
>>> transform('Test2.wma')
('Test2.wma',)
>>> transform('Test3.1100,456.jpg')
('Test3', '1100,456', 'jpg')
>>> transform('T.E.S.T.4.5,6.png')
('T.E.S.T.4', '5,6', 'png')
>>> transform('Test5,7,8.sss')
('Test5,7,8.sss',)
>>> transform('Test6.2,3,4.png')
('Test6.2,3,4.png',)
>>> transform('Test7.5,6.7,8.test')
('Test7', '5,6', '7,8', 'test')
```

To also get the file extension split off when there are no matches, you can use the following:

```
def transform(s):
    s = re.sub(r'(\.\d+,\d+)+\.', lambda m: m.group(0).replace('.', '\n'), s)
    groups = s.split('\n')
    groups[-1:] = groups[-1].rsplit('.', 1)
    return tuple(groups)
```

This will be the same output as above except that `'Test2.wma'` becomes `('Test2', 'wma')`, with similar behavior for `'Test5,7,8.sss'` and `'Test5,7,8.sss'`.

Comment: Also if the last group contains more than one `.` you will end up splitting the last group several times.

Comment: Just modified it to use `\n` instead of a space, you could also use something like `\x00` to be more sure it won't be included in a valid string.

Comment: `transform('.a.a.a.a.a.a.') == ('', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '')`

Comment: @nneonneo ahh I see, I forgot the count argument to `rsplit`, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the example!  I really need to take the time to learn more about regex, it's so powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$`

Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/vrgm6) >>

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test1.0,0.csv')
[('Test1', '0,0', 'csv')]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test2.wma')
[]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test3.1100,456.jpg')
[('Test3', '1100,456', 'jpg')]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'T.E.S.T.4.5,6.png')
[('T.E.S.T.4', '5,6', 'png')]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test5,7,8.sss')
[]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test6.2,3,4.png')
[]
```

---

```
>>> print re.findall(r'^([^,]+)\.(\d+,\d+)\.([^,.]+)$', 'Test7.5,6.7,8.test') 
[]
```

Comment: What does this produce for: `Test.xx,yz.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^(.+)\.((\d+,\d+)\.)?(.+)$/'
```

The third capturing group should contain the pair of numbers. If you have multiple of those pairs, you should get multiple matches. And the third capturing would always contain the pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?)\.(\d+,\d+)\.(.*?)$
```

This passes your tests, at least in Patterns:

[image: Passing tests in Patterns]

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close, does python support named groups?

```
^.*(?P<group1>\d+(?:,\d+)?)\.(?P<group2>\d+(?:,\d+)?).*\..+$
```

Comment: The named group syntax is `(?P<name>pattern)`