# RegEx VBA Excel complex string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a function pulled from [here](https://excelicious.wordpress.com/code-samples/vba/regex-functions/).  My problem is that I don't know what RegEx pattern I need to use to split out the following data:

```
+1 vorpal unholy longsword +31/+26/+21/+16 (2d6+13)
+1 vorpal flaming whip +30/+25/+20 (1d4+7 plus 1d6 fire and entangle)
2 slams +31 (1d10+12)
```

I want it to look like:

```
+1 vorpal unholy longsword, 31 
+1 vorpal flaming whip, 30 
2 slams, 31
```

Here is the VBA code that does the RegExp validation:

```
Public Function RXGET(ByRef find_pattern As Variant, _
                        ByRef within_text As Variant, _
                        Optional ByVal submatch As Long = 0, _
                        Optional ByVal start_num As Long = 0, _
                        Optional ByVal case_sensitive As Boolean = True) As Variant
' RXGET - Looks for a match for regular expression pattern find_pattern
' in the string within_text and returns it if found, error otherwise.
' Optional long submatch may be used to return the corresponding submatch
' if specified - otherwise the entire match is returned.
' Optional long start_num specifies the number of the character to start
' searching for in within_text. Default=0.
' Optional boolean case_sensitive makes the regex pattern case sensitive
' if true, insensitive otherwise. Default=true.

Dim objRegex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim colMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Dim vbsMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim colSubMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.SubMatches
Dim sMatchString As String

Set objRegex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

' Initialise Regex object
With objRegex
    .Global = False
    ' Default is case sensitive
    If case_sensitive Then
        .IgnoreCase = False
    Else: .IgnoreCase = True
    End If
    .pattern = find_pattern
End With

' Return out of bounds error
If start_num >= Len(within_text) Then
    RXGET = CVErr(xlErrNum)
    Exit Function
End If
sMatchString = Right$(within_text, Len(within_text) - start_num)

' Create Match collection
Set colMatch = objRegex.Execute(sMatchString)
If colMatch.Count = 0 Then ' No match
    RXGET = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Else
    Set vbsMatch = colMatch(0)
    If submatch = 0 Then ' Return match value
        RXGET = vbsMatch.Value
    Else
        Set colSubMatch = vbsMatch.SubMatches ' Use the submatch collection
        If colSubMatch.Count < submatch Then
            RXGET = CVErr(xlErrNum)
        Else
            RXGET = CStr(colSubMatch(submatch - 1))
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: A few things for clarification. Do you have 3 (or more) strings or one multiline string? In the latter case, do you want a multiline string back, or are you good with a bunch of single line strings (one for each match)? Is it okay if you get every of those lines in the result as one string, or do you need the 3 separate parts (first number, name, last number)?

Comment: The first grey code block is one long line with a comma, and or or separating the information. i.e. cell B2  The second grey code block should be in three subsequent cells. i.e. C2, D2 and E2.

Comment: Here is what I have currently, but it gets me the first + and the second.    =PERSONAL.xlsb!RXGET("([A-Za-z0-9\+{1} ]+)",CX2,1,0,FALSE)

Comment: You don't need to escape `+` within character classes. Also, I don't think that the `{1}` does any good in there. Have a look at my attempt. If it doesn't work, let me know. Then it's something Excel specific and I need to figure out the specifics of your regex flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Excel but this should get you started on the RegEx:

```
/(?:^|, |and |or )(\+?\d?\s?[^\+]*?) (?:\+|-)(\d+)/
```

**NOTE:** There is a slight caveat here. This will also match if an element begins with `+` only (not being followed by a digit).

Capture groups 1 and 2 contain the strings that go left and right of your comma (if the whole pattern has index 0). So you can something like `capture[1] + ', ' + capture[2]` (whatever your syntax for that is).

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
/(?:^|, |and |or )         # make sure that we only start looking after
                           # the beginning of the string, after a comma, after an
                           # and or after an or; the "?:" makes sure that this
                           # subpattern is not capturing
 (\+?                      # a literal "+"
 \d+                       # at least one digit
                           # a literal space
 [^+]*?)                   # arbitrarily many non-plus characters; the ? makes it
                           # non-greedy, otherwise it might span multiple lines
                           # a literal space
 \+                        # a literal "+"
 (\d+)/                    # at least one digit (and the brakets are for capturing)
```

Comment: I receive an error with the above RegEx.  Here is the allowed literals for VBAScript RegEx.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic2

Comment: try removing the `?:` at the beginning. however, the capturing groups you're interested in, would then be 2 and 3 instead of 1 and 2, respectively

Comment: "an error"? Do you have something more specific by any chance?

Comment: your input _does_ look like this, doesn't it? `+1 vorpal unholy longsword +31/+26/+21/+16 (2d6+13) and +1 vorpal flaming whip +30/+25/+20 (1d4+7 plus 1d6 fire and entangle), 2 slams +31 (1d10+12)`

Comment: It looks like this: +1 vorpal unholy longsword +31/+26/+21/+16 (2d6+13), +1 vorpal flaming whip +30/+25/+20 (1d4+7 plus 1d6 fire and entangle) or 2 slams +31 (1d10+12)
Also, the error means that the RegEx is returning no found data.

Comment: Hm try to escape the `+` within the character class `[^+]` ... it seems odd, but if that's not it, I'm out of guesses

Comment: OK, almost there.  That works for anything that begins with a + or a number, but not say bite +1 (1d3-1).

Comment: ah okay, I didn't know, that this was a possible string, give me a second

Comment: I actually had to use /(?:^|, |and |or )(\+?\d?\s?[^\+]*?) \+(\d+)/ to get the data.  Thanks I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I was trying something similar, because you regex will also match `+ bite +1 (1d3-1)`. But my examples all become greedy (matching up to a preceding `and`) in some edge cases. But good that you have found something that works for you :)

Comment: Well, I can't get the data after comma, and or or.  I would have thought the next block of matches would be 3 and 4 then 5 and 6 for the third block.  However, this does not work.  Also, this does not match heavy mace -1 (1d8-1) and swarm (2d6).  So anything with - or no bonus before the (.

Comment: Ummm no. Unfortunately, I don't know about VBA. But in most languages there is a way to "match all". Then you would get an array where each element contains a 1 and a 2 with the respective matches. Sometimes it's the other way round. 1 is an array of all first captures, and 2 is an array of all second captures. So try googling for something like "VBA regex match all"

Comment: I figured out how to get 3, 4, 5 and 6.  I am still having problems extracting heavy mace -1 (1d8-1) and swarm (2d6). So anything with - or no bonus before the (.

Comment: try changing the \+ at the end to (?:\+|-), that fixes the mace. no bonus is a bit trickier

Comment: no wait, try this: `/(?:^|, |and |or )(\+?\d?\s?[^\+-]*?) (?!\+|-)(\d+)/` ... but this still doesn't include the swarm. does **every** single match end with something in round brackets?

Comment: sorry, my bad again. I meant to write it like this: `/(?:^|, |and |or )(\+?\d?\s?[^\+-]*?) (?:\+|-)(\d+)/` ... still working on the swarm

Comment: this is getting gradually more complicated. next time you ask a regex question, I suggest that you make a very extensive list of possible inputs, make clear what the variables and what the fixed parts are, and show us what you want as the output. also include these tiny details like how your parts are actually separated (that there are 'and' and 'or' and ',' in between is pretty essential). take this as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608152/python-regex-match-in-string

Comment: My original question had that info, but a moderator changed my question to a different format.

Comment: oh, that's annoying. but I can see why ^^. hm, you could try to wrap the whole regex in `()` and then handle every possible structure separately (separated by `|`). It's not that elegant, but with those switches inside the regex I keep getting greediness problems, because of the `and` in one of the brackets.

Comment: That's fine.  Out of the 2029 lines there are only 20 some that the RegEx doesn't trap so I will just hand type those.  Again, I really appreciate your help for not just answering my question, but also explaining how it works!