# how to remove anything without numbers and extension with regex?

Tags: php, regex

i have file like this `1248812832.v.doc` and i want to remove strings and dots frome database fields to make the file like this `1248812832.doc`

i use this code but it not work perfectly i still see strings and dots

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'alsidik';

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db($database)) {
    echo "Unable to select " . $database . ": " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM d_jobs";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['jb_id'];
    $jb_cv = $row['jb_cv'];
    $jb_rep = preg_replace('/[^.a-z0-9.]/','', $jb_cv);
    $sql = "UPDATE d_jobs set jb_cv='" .$jb_rep. "' where jb_id=" . $id;
    mysql_query($sql);
}

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

can anyone help me..thanks

Comment: Are all the filenames going to be in the same format? Because if they are, you can use `explode()` instead of a regex

Comment: i mean in database field

Comment: So are they the same format or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the `explode` solution: Just cast it to `int` and put the extension back on:

```
$str = '1248812832abc.v.doc';

$name = (int) $str . '.' .pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

var_dump($name);
```

[Example on codepad](http://codepad.org/OpiBumPC).

Comment: +1, looks like your crystal ball skills are better than mine. )

Comment: @raina77ow The comments below your (already upvoted...) answer helped ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say how would you want to process this string:

```
$str = '1212.v.a.doc';
```

... so I assume you need only the first and the last parts of this string (where parts are delimited by '.' symbols). With this, you can use either...

```
$parts = explode('.', $str);
if (count($parts) > 2) {
  $str = "$parts[0].{$parts[count($parts)-1]}";
}
```

... or

```
$str = preg_replace('#(?<=[.])([^.]*[.])+#', '', $str);
```

The reason for this line to fail:

```
preg_replace('/[^.a-z0-9.]/','', $jb_cv);
```

... is that you use a negative character class here (defined by `[^...]` part). In other words, you erase all symbols but dots, lowercase latin letters and digits from your string. That's definitely not what's wanted, I suppose; in fact, it won't alter the original string in your example at all.

**UPDATE:** Looks like all that jugglery was in vain, and what you actually needed is just digits and extension. Well, it can be done with regex too:

```
$str = '1212.v.a.doc';
$str = preg_replace('#^(\d+).*([.][^.]+)$#', '$1$2', $str);
echo $str;
```

... but in fact I'd prefer the @jeroen's solution for readability alone. )

Comment: you dont understand me... i just need to remove anything and the file be like this 1248812832.doc...i just need regular expression in php

Comment: And how this is different from my answer?

Comment: @user1673473 please provide more examples of possible filenames. even examples which arent't affected. how do you expect us to understand what you want from one example? we could solve that example by hardcoding the return value.

Comment: this is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608152/python-regex-match-in-string

Comment: because i still test it and see fields like this 1693558033ahmedghoniemcv.doc ..try this site http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

Comment: Can you give clear examples of string inputs and outputs in your question? Do you want all your filenames to look like this: `\d+[.]someext?`

Comment: ok...892824765cv.doc.....1248812832.c.v.doc.......1006703548ostafadelabeahousef.doc.......1928994399eh.docx

Comment: It's inputs; how should the corresponding outputs look like?

Comment: what's so hard about making a little table of these like in the link I gave you?